# NoMethodError (undefined method `first' for nil:NilClass) when trying to post an image with paperclip and aws-sdk gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, amazon-s3, paperclip

I recently added the paperclip gem to my web app. I then added aws-sdk so that i can upload images on the production version of my app, which is on heroku. After configuring everything and trying to upload an image, i got the standard rails error page, and went to the log:

```
NameError (uninitialized constant Paperclip::Storage::S3::AWS):
app/controllers/pins_controller.rb:23:in `create'
```

I searched online and found out that this was a problem with the version-2 of aws-sdk, and that i had to downgrade the gem. So i downgraded the gem so that it uses version-1, then ran bundle install, commited my changes with git, and pushed it to heroku.

This time, when i tried to attach a photo to a pin, i got a different error. This led me to believe that the previous error was fixed and that i now have a different problem. Here is the error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `first' for nil:NilClass):
app/controllers/pins_controller.rb:23:in `create'
```

I did lots of research, and have not been able to find out what's going wrong. I'm a beginner with rails and i'm learning it by making a web app similar to pinterest, where i can allows users to make accounts and post pins, and i'm using devise to do this. I added paperclip so that i can enable image posting, and aws-sdk so that i can use amazon S3 for storing photos due to the fact that my production evironment is on heroku, and heroku can't store images. I will paste in some more helpful code:

**Controller**(app/controllers/pins_controller.rb): This is the controller file which is mentioned in the error log. The error is on line 23, like it says on the log. Line 23 is the line in the "create" action that says: if @pin.save

```
    class PinsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_pin, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :correct_user, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]

  def index
    @pins = Pin.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @pin = current_user.pins.build
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @pin = current_user.pins.build(pin_params)

    if @pin.save

      redirect_to @pin, notice: 'Pin was successfully added.'
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def update
    if @pin.update(pin_params)
      redirect_to @pin, notice: 'Pin was successfully edited.'
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @pin.destroy
    redirect_to pins_url, notice: 'Pin was successfully deleted.'
  end

  private
    def set_pin
      @pin = Pin.find(params[:id])
    end

    def correct_user
      @pin = current_user.pins.find_by(id: params[:id])
      redirect_to pins_path, notice: "You are not permitted to edit this pin" if @pin.nil?
    end

    def pin_params
      params.require(:pin).permit(:description, :image)
    end
end
```

**Model**(app/models/pin.rb): This is the model for the pins(which are basically posts)

```
    class Pin < ActiveRecord::Base
        belongs_to :user

        has_attached_file :image, styles: { medium: "300x300>", thumb: "100x100>" }
        validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
    end
```

**Config**(config/environments/production.rb): This is the production file where i added the aws configuration variables

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # Code is not reloaded between requests.
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Eager load code on boot. This eager loads most of Rails and
  # your application in memory, allowing both threaded web servers
  # and those relying on copy on write to perform better.
  # Rake tasks automatically ignore this option for performance.
  config.eager_load = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Enable Rack::Cache to put a simple HTTP cache in front of your application
  # Add `rack-cache` to your Gemfile before enabling this.
  # For large-scale production use, consider using a caching reverse proxy like
  # NGINX, varnish or squid.
  # config.action_dispatch.rack_cache = true

  # Disable serving static files from the `/public` folder by default since
  # Apache or NGINX already handles this.
  config.serve_static_files = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  # config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

  # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
  config.assets.compile = false

  # Asset digests allow you to set far-future HTTP expiration dates on all assets,
  # yet still be able to expire them through the digest params.
  config.assets.digest = true

  # `config.assets.precompile` and `config.assets.version` have moved to config/initializers/assets.rb

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files.
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Sendfile' # for Apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for NGINX

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  # config.force_ssl = true

  # Use the lowest log level to ensure availability of diagnostic information
  # when problems arise.
  config.log_level = :debug

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags.
  # config.log_tags = [ :subdomain, :uuid ]

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups.
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(SyslogLogger.new)

  # Use a different cache store in production.
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server.
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = 'http://assets.example.com'

  # Ignore bad email addresses and do not raise email delivery errors.
  # Set this to true and configure the email server for immediate delivery to raise delivery errors.
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation cannot be found).
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Use default logging formatter so that PID and timestamp are not suppressed.
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

  # Do not dump schema after migrations.
  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false

  config.paperclip_defaults = {
  :storage => :s3,
  :s3_credentials => {
    :bucket => ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME'],
    :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
    :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
  }
}
end
```

**Form**(app/views/pins/_form.html.erb): This is the form which is used to submit pins

```
<%= form_for @pin, html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>
  <% if @pin.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@pin.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this pin from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @pin.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :image %><br>
    <%= f.file_field :image, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :description %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :description, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.submit class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**Migration**(db/migrate/20150902154233_add_attachment_image_to_pins.rb): This is the migration i did so that i can attach photos to my pins

```
class AddAttachmentImageToPins < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    change_table :pins do |t|
      t.attachment :image
    end
  end

  def self.down
    remove_attachment :pins, :image
  end
end
```

**Gemfile**: This is my gemfile, i'm using rails4, paperclip 4.3, and aws-sdk 1.6.5

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.2.1'

gem 'rails', '4.2.4'

gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'

gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'

gem 'jquery-rails'

gem 'turbolinks'

gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.5' 

gem 'devise', '~> 3.5.2'

gem "paperclip", "~> 4.3"

gem 'aws-sdk', '< 2.0'


group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'

  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
    gem 'pg'
    gem 'rails_12factor'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end
```

I am really stuck right now, and i don't know what to do. I hope someone can help. If there's something i forgot to add, please tell me and i will add it.

Comment: You didn't show the User model.  Does User have many Pins?  I would personally try building/creating in the Rails console and double checking my logs for other clues like unpermitted attributes.  Also, I think `gem 'aws-sdk-v1'` might be safer, although I agree you are likely past that issue.

Comment: Hey man, thanks for your help. After hours of being really pissed off, it started working again. This must be because of one of the things that i tried. I was able to create a pin with an image, but at first it showed an empty image. Then i knew that it had something to do with S3, so i figured out how to fix it. I made a new bucket which is located in US standard, and the images started showing. Thanks anyways.= :)

Comment: Awesome glad to hear it is working for you

Answer (score 0):

**I figured it out**

I made it work after trying different things. Look at the comment to see what i did.